# Using head to see up to a character

Tags: head

I have some C source files and a lot of them have a single, 1-line comment at the top that offers a short description of what that program does (I haven't done anything complex enough to warrant a full paragraph.) I was wondering if it was possible to use head to see up to the first `#`, since that that would be my first preprocessor directive. If it printed line numbers, that would also be a bonus.

Comment: sounds like a job for grep?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grep is probably a better solution, using the context switch `-B`:

```
grep -B999 -m 1 "^#" file.c
```

or, with long option names:

```
grep --before-context 999 --max-count 1 "^#" file.c
```

This finds the pattern `"^#"` (a '#' anchored at the beginning of the line), shows up to 999 lines **before** it, with a maximum number of "^#"'s found of 1.

So basically, find the first "^#", show up to 999 lines before it, and quit.  You might want to pipe through head to remove the found "^#":

```
grep -B999 -m1 "^#" file.c | head -n -1
```

Which will cut off the last line.

I agree that `-B999` might be a bit excessive, but I'd hate to cut off anything you write later in your career after you get wordy.  Adjust as appropriate, of course.